# jQuery count link and element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a simple jquery snippet where I add a number on the hand of counted elements to each element. But is something going wrong.

I add a link and element with a number for each existing element as `#links span`, but in the beginning my function gives the numbers 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc to the link number, because he sees no `#links span`'s the first time.

Watch my jsFiddle to understand my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/RVermeulen/26VeD/

```
function numbers() {
    var number = 0;
    if($('#links span').length <= 1) {
        number = 1;       
    } else {
        number = $('#links span').length;       
    }
    return number;

}

$('#add').on('click', function() {
    $('#links').append('<span number="'+ numbers() +'">Link'+ numbers() +'</span><br />'); 
   $('#elements').append('<div class="element">Element '+ numbers() +'</div>'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like this

```
function numbers() {
    return $('#links span').length;
}

$('#add').on('click', function () {
    $('#links').append('<span number="' + numbers() + '">Link' + (numbers() + 1) + '</span><br />');
    $('#elements').append('<div class="element">Element ' + numbers() + '</div>');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/26VeD/21/)

Comment: OP probably wants `.length + 1`, also, there is no need to `parseInt` an int

Comment: @AnoopJoshi Yes I do, but can do it in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are callng Multiple times the number() updating the value that function return try:

```
function numbers() {
    var number = $('#links span').length + 1; 
    return number;

}

$('#add').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $numb = numbers();
    $('#links').append('<span number="'+ $numb +'">Link'+ $numb +'</span><br />'); 
   $('#elements').append('<div class="element">Element '+ $numb +'</div>'); 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj97M/1/)

Comment: Beware that you're not `var`ing `number`, also an upper case first letter variable for a non-constructor is unusual in _JavaScript_

Comment: Done, I was writing fast :) so at the fiddle I declare number like global var. thank for correction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#add').on('click', function() {
    var number=$('.element').length+1;
   $('#elements').append('<div class="element">Element '+ number +'</div>');
      $('#links').append('<span number="'+ numbers +'">Link'+ number +'</span><br />');
});
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26VeD/28/)**

Answer (score 0):

First you call `number()` function lot times. There is no need for this. Simple write:

```
$('#add').on('click', function() {   
    var num = numbers();

   $('#links').append('<span number="'+ num +'">Link'+ num +'</span><br />'); 
   $('#elements').append('<div class="element">Element '+ num +'</div>'); 
});
```

Second you need to increase by 1 length of `span` each time so i ended to this:

```
function numbers() {
     return   number = $('#links span').length + 1;       
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/26VeD/35/)